# I need assistance that how can I solve my stripe connection error?

Tags: php, sockets, stripe-payments

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://api.stripe.com:443 (Connection timed out) in /home/genphics/public_html/incrediblewebs.com/payment_link/stripe-secure-payment/stripe/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php on line 417

I need answer that how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error usually comes from your server's configuration. Something is preventing you from making outgoing network requests to Stripe. It might be a firewall rule or something similar. One potential way to debug this is to run Stripe's [reachability tool](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability) on your server to try and narrow it down. The next step is usually to talk to your networking/IT team if you have one or your hosting provider otherwise.